# escaping characters neo4j batch loader

Tags: csv, neo4j

I'm trying to import an edge list using the csv importer, but I get an error message due to what I think is a failure to escape a character. Is there a way around this, or do I have to run some script on the csv files to handle this?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "'Abelmoschus esculentus' bunchy to
phytoplasma"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.id(Importer.java:213)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.id(Importer.java:181)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.importRelationships(Importer.java:147)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.doImport(Importer.java:232)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.main(Importer.java:83)
```

Comment: https://github.com/jexp/batch-import

Comment: Yes, I am using the batch importer

Answer (score 0):

use the config option: `batch_import.csv.quotes=true`